# Failed to connect to '${ip}:${port}': Connection refused randomly

Tags: android, adb

I followed the steps every time.

```
 > adb usb
 > adb tcpip ${port}
 > adb connect ${ip_from_ifconfig}:${port}
```

I got the IP address from `> ifconfig | grep "inet"`.

Sometimes I added the followings command before `> adb usb`.

```
 > adb kill-server
 > adb start-server
```

It succeeded or failed repetitively. 
Let me know What's wrong with these steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I gotcha what's the problem it was.
It's possible to have another IP address from IP address of laptop when you use wifi also.

That's why you should get the IP address of your android device.

```
  Settings > About tablet (or About phone) > Status > IP address
```

In conclusion, there are two IP address that are `${IP_1}` from laptop and `${IP_2}` from mobile.
So you should put the IP2 address when you try connecting mobile device like:

```
  > adb tcpip 5577
  > adb connect ${IP_2}:5577
```

I hope you can save your time from this.
Happy coding!